# Use separate ringtones for multiple lines on one iPhone‌

Tags: iphone, ios, ringtones

For people with an iPhone having [dual SIMs/eSIMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_SIM) for two phone numbers, can a default ringtone be set for each phone number separately?

Multiple sources on the Web say this is not possible.

Yet [this article](https://www.macrumors.com/2023/09/13/ios-17-ringtones-text-tones/) on MacRumors says about iOS 17:

> you can use separate ringtones if you have multiple lines on one ‌iPhone‌.

Is that actually possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In iOS 17, in *Settings > Sounds & Haptics > Ringtone*, you should see ringtone options for your different SIM cards, you can now choose a ringtone per SIM card.

That's what I found from various online sources (paraphrased by me). This feature seems indeed to be concerning only iOS 17, older articles or QAs clearly state that it isn't possible on prior versions.

Also, [New features available  with iOS 17 - Apple.com](https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-17/pdf/iOS_All_New_Features.pdf) states:

> If you use dual SIM, you can set **different ringtones per SIM** and choose either SIM card to return a phone call from an unknown caller.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

---

See details and screenshots in [this article](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/how-to/how-to-keep-different-ringtones-for-each-sim-on-iphone/) at MacObserver.com.